# Silver Bracelet Photography with 100% pure white Background

Tags: product-photography, background, color-white, jewelry

i am selling Bracelet in Amazon and i am facing hard time taking white back photography for silver bracelets. The following image is from another seller. This is the quality i needed.

[image]

But all i getting is these...

[image]

This too after editing with photoshop (I crease brightness which compromises the bracelet quality).

I have DSLR camera. I tried using different backgrounds like paper, boards, cloth, etc., But nothing seems to work for me.

Can anyone please help me how to achieve 100% pure white background without compromising quality?

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that the example bracelet is sitting on a light table, being lit from underneath. This makes things a little simpler since you have no shadows, and the light source won't be bouncing off the top of the bracelet. You can use white, black, or colored cards to create whatever reflection pattern you want without worrying about creating shadows. You can easily emulate this with a sheet of translucent glass or plastic with your light placed underneath.